# Querying MomentJS dates on IndexedDB & AngularJS - Dates vs Strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs, indexeddb

So, I just had a big "Oh Snap!" moment.

I'm using MomentJS with AngularJS and IndexedDB in an offline app.

All my records are stored with an index `date_idx` based on the date property of the object.

The problem comes when I try to run queries based on the date using the following code:

```
$scope.redoresults = function(){
  $indexedDB.openStore('records', function(store){
    $scope.upper =  moment($scope.dates.endDate).format("DD[/]MM[/]YYYY");
    $scope.downer =  moment($scope.dates.startDate).format("DD[/]MM[/]YYYY");

    var find = store.query();
    find = find.$between($scope.downer, $scope.upper, false, false);
    find = find.$index("date_idx");
    store.eachWhere(find).then(function(e){
        $scope.daterange = e;
        console.log($scope.daterange);
    });
  });
};
```

The query was delivering weird results, sometimes correct, sometimes not. 
Until I realized that I'm actually querying against strings, not dates.
Being so, a **query between 01/08/2016 and 31/08/2016**, will still deliver me results containing **20/09/2016**, because as a number it's indeed between the range.

I feel I'm missing something structure-wise.

Any comment on how to solve this issue?

Should I query against some other index? But then how can I compare the dates?

Comment: store dates as ISO strings or timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Store dates as dates, and query using dates.
- Or, store dates as timestamps (e.g. date.getTime()), and then query using timestamps
- Do not store dates as dates and then query with a string date, this will produce junk.
- Do not store dates as strings, and then query with a string date, this will produce junk. String values are compared lexicographically which can easily depart from how dates are compared.